# Excel shortcut not working on french keyboard

Tags: excel, excel-2013

I am using excel 2013, on a french keyboard. I want to use a simple shortcut,

```
CTRL + SHIFT + ;
```

to have a static time in a cell.

```
CTRL + ;
```

works perfectly, writing the date.
Is this a known issue ; can it be an issue due to my computer specifically, and  is there a way to change default excel shortcuts if it is ?

Comment: No idea about the french keyboard, but I'm pretty sure, that this is not an excel issue. But: You can add shortcuts in excel via Options > Quick Access Toolbar. Have a look at this: http://www.excel-university.com/create-keyboard-shortcuts-for-your-favorite-excel-commands/

Comment: Does it work on another cell or in another workbook? This now sounds more like you having turned off some kind of option.

Comment: What happens if you use `Ctrl + Shift + ,`?

Comment: @Tom nothing, and `Ctrl + Shift + :` tells me "no correponding cells" (rough translation)

Comment: The preset shortcut for `date` and `time` is different for each country. In most EU countries the shortcut for `date` is `Ctrl + Shift + ,` and for time it is `Ctrl + Shift + .`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it, it is simply `CTRL + :` to print statically the current time. I will also report this to Microsoft so that [this](https://support.office.com/fr-fr/article/Ins%C3%A9rer-la-date-et-l-heure-dans-une-cellule-Excel-2013-d12a87b2-2379-45b0-a58d-63aec27ba48f) page is updated.

`CTRL + ;` works fine for printing the date.